# Preventing text wrapping a DIV

Tags: html, css

There should be a simple solution to this, but so far it's eluded me.

This is what I want to achieve, inside a single td:

```
text text
 text txt [div [img][img] ]
txt t txt
```

The div just protects the two imgs from getting moved around promiscuously (they're buttons, the left one sometimes invisible, and need to stay side by side) The text, which can vary in length, needs to line up flush-right with the div, not wrap it.

Because of the amount of massaging I have to do on updates, which are frequent, I can't solve it by using a second td to hold the div, tho that would otherwise be ideal.

This is the basic code for one item (there are several, assembled into a string in a for loop, which is then written to an .innerHTML)

```
'<td class="Label" id="rank'+i+
    '">Some text of<br>arbitrary, but not great,<br>length'+
    '<div class="x">'+untie_button('off')+tie_button(i)+'</div></td>'
```

Class Label declares color, font, and text-align:right

Class x declares some padding and vertical-align:middle.

The routines untie_button and tie_button are trivial, merely returning the appropriate img with an id indexed by i attached.

I get one of 2 results, depending on what flavoring I try:  the text is completely above the div, or it wraps the div.

Comment: Without further information, and with pure javascript I would refer you to [appendChild()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) respectively to [insertBefore()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp)

Comment: Can you please provide some code to show what you have tried so far and to illustrate the problem(s) you're encountering?

Comment: Please put into a codepen or JSfiddle. Hard to comprehend this

Comment: @Ben Rondeau:  I already answered my own question (see below).

Answer (score 0):

Putting the text to be flush-righted into a span declared inline-block, followed by the div also declared inline-block, inside the td declared with vertical-align:middle seems to do the job well enough for my purposes (it has little adaptability).  I'd to move the id from the td to the span, but that's okay since I'm not trying to modify the td as such.

*sigh*  Hope this helps someone else.